# UI design pattern for true/false/null (for inheritance of values)?

Tags: design-patterns, inheritance, user-interface, acl, tuples

I'm trying my best to figure out a succinct, straightforward widget, using standard UI widgets available in any toolkit (e.g., checkboxes, radio buttons, or listboxes), that could model a true/false/null value.

Why am I trying to do this? I'm storing a tree in a database (go ahead, criticise me for storing hierarchical information in a relational store) and the simple inheritance model is that if something doesn't have a value, it defaults to its parent's value.

What I have right now is two checkboxes:

```
[ ] Can custom-order    [ ] default (currently yes)
```

Checking 'default' will disable the first checkbox. Does that make sense though? I thought of another widget, which uses less scripting:

```
Can custom order:    ( ) yes    ( ) no    ( ) default (currently yes)
```

Which makes more sense to you? I'm starting to lean more towards the second. And if anyone has any other suggestions, I'd be grateful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I much prefer the second, which makes it clear that there are three values, and one of them is an inherited value. Two checkboxes logically provide *four* values.

The only thing I might add is something to indicate where the default is coming from. Since this might clutter up the page, it could be a tooltip on the default option.

Comment: I would only add that default might say inherit instead.

Comment: Thanks! I'm surprised that everyone says 'inherit' is better, cuz to me it's such computery terminology, and the people who are using my web app aren't very computery.

I get what you're saying about two checkboxes providing four values. As I mentioned, my code disabled the first when the second was checked, but it seemed ugly to me.

Answer (score 2):

To me, the second is more intuitive.  And fwiw -- when we've set up similar controls at my firm we've used the label *inherit* (instead of default) for the pass-through setting.

Comment: I'm out of votes for today or I'd vote this up for *inherit* -- much clearer terminology.

Comment: Thanks! So you think 'inherit' is best too, eh? Well, inherit it is!